# Symfony update Entity value + 1

Tags: mysql, symfony, sum, addition

I would like to summate or add one up while I update an existing db entry.

For the Reason that I will have to work with MagicCalls, I just wonder how I can handle this.

In raw sql, I would do it like:

```
UPDATE table SET value= value + 1 WHERE ....
```

But in this case, I have absolutely no idea how to work it out.

My code looks like:

Entity:

```
class Properties
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Sport", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
 */
private $sport;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Entertainment", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
 */
private $entertainment;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Wellness", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
 */
private $wellness;
```

Now, I get those column names by

```
$metadata = $em->getClassMetadata($className);
$columnNames=$metadata->getColumnNames();
```

I recieve an array, which I can foreach and add values to each of them which I will have to write back by using an accessor:

```
$properties= new Properties();
$accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessorBuilder()
                        ->enableMagicCall()
                        ->getPropertyAccessor();


 foreach($columnNames as $merkmale) {
     $accessor->setValue($properties, $merkmale, 1);
 }
```

So how can I handle an update by counting one up ? I missed something I guess

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [Lifecycle callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks)? This way you can choose [doctrine event](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html) which suits your case best and increment all values you need in one method.

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity()
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/
class Properties
{
    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="Sport", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
    */
    private $sport;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="Entertainment", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
    */
    private $entertainment;

    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="Wellness", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
    */
    private $wellness;

    /**
    * @ORM\PrePersist
    */
    public function incrementValues()
    {
        $this->entertainment = 1; //you don't need any magic any more
        $this->wellness = $this->wellness + 5; //you can access your entity values directly
    }

}
```

All you need to do is annotate your entity with `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` and add method which you also need to annotate with given event, like `@ORM\PrePersist` and this method will be called by `doctrine` each time this event occurs

Comment: Awww... haven't seen this existing. But if I don't missunderstood, it will always update all given Fields. In my case, there might be only  special fields which has to be updated.

For example, the input-array contains only the value "sport" which has to be updated.

Comment: no, doctrine will just always call a method annotated with event annotation - which fields will you update is just a matter of logic you will put in this method

Comment: sorry. I guess I dont' get it  :( For example, if there is an array with ['sport','wellness'], and I will update both fields by using the MagicCall, how should the method look like for it?

Comment: now I don't get it. What do you want to increment (+1)? you cannot increment array. And what is MagicCall?

Comment: I get the  Values of the entity within an array.  therefor I need to use the MagicCall eg. the PropertyAccessor to write these back.

Comment: normaly, you would do a " setSport("whatever"); In my case, I do a $accessor->setValue($property, $merkmale, "whatever");

Comment: now you don't need any magic any more, check my edit: now you just do ``$this->sport = 'whatever'``

Comment: Oh wow. thats really tricky and so simple. Thank you, I think this is the easiest and best solution.